# "...dass er **wachen Sinnes** zu träumen glaubte"

Tags: genitive

> ... denn das Licht auf den Gesichtern der Elben und der Wohlklang ihrer wechselvollen und geschmeidigen Stimmen nahmen ihn so sehr gefangen, dass er **wachen Sinnes** zu träumen glaubte.

Ich möchte wissen, um was für einen Genitiv es sich dabei handelt, und wo ich mehr Informationen dazu erhalten könnte, da ich auf so etwas (soweit es mir einfällt) erst gerade zum ersten Mal gestoßen bin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ich würde sagen, das ist ein **genitivus qualitatis**, also ein Genitiv der Eigenschaft. Man kann nämlich sagen: *Ich bin wachen Sinnes.* Andere feststehende Beispiele im Deutschen sind:

> reinen Gewissens
>
> sehenden Auges
>
> stehenden Fußes

Comment: *stehenden Fußes* ist noch so ein Ausdruck.

Comment: @Janka Ja, guter Hinweis! Ich habs mal mit in den Text der Antwort übernommen.